# Force save/commit of MSSQL data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 tables that are linked in same DB. One contains details the other has an overview.

```
public SqlConnection conn;

    public bool Open()
    {
        if (conn != null && conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            return true;
        }

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


  public bool InsertFilledAndUpdateOrder(long orderID, string newStatus int execSignedAmount)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!InsertFilled(orderID, "Filled",  execSignedAmount))
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

           //At this point I can see inserted record in MSSM

        try
        {
           //BUT this next query does NOT see it - until I step back in debugger and excute this line again!
            if (!UpdateOrderFromFilled(orderID))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

InsertFilled() and UpdateOrderFromFilled() are complex paramterised queries that I am not showing for simplicity.

The above coded was working well UNTIL I changed it to be on a background thread - hence this is some kind of thread issue.

The docs for ExecuteNonQuery says it block until insert/update is completed. However, in this case although changes are in DB, my next query does not see them!

Comment: Don't share connection objects like that. It's unnecessary and leaky. Just create and dispose of the connection as you need it. Windows will connection pool to optimise the actual connections for you, you don't need to do this yourself

Comment: Never share `SqlConnection` objects across scopes; there's just no need for it and it's a rife source of problems. I have no idea if that's any relation to your issue, but it's worth fixing regardless. Use `using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...)) { ... }` consistently. Connection pooling takes care of the rest. If you actually need statements to happen in the same scope (because they're part of the same transaction) then *put* them in the same scope.

Comment: This ^ is possibly your issue but your "background thread" code is relevant too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What do you mean by "same scope"? Same Method?

Comment: Same *block* `{ }`. Including but not limited to the same method. The scope of an `SqlConnection` object should basically be as small as possible, and is usually just wrapping a single statement (or batch of statements if they're logically part of the same transaction). Sharing instances across threads is definitely out. (Well, unless you explicitly synchronize, but then there's no point.) A connection that encounters an error breaks and is no longer usable *and* a connection is not thread-safe. This makes it very unattractive to share or reuse them, even if there was a need.

Comment: Also, I create 2 large complex parametized queries. If I recode to "using conn = new SqlConnection". I will need to do that setup each time - which in a high-frequency app (which this is) is likely to slow me down wouldn't it? How do I get around this is issue?

Comment: No. You are vastly overestimating the time it takes to create these objects (CPU instructions) as opposed to actually executing the statement, which takes I/O (think order of magnitude). That said, you *can* further optimize this by reusing `SqlCommand` instances -- that's OK. You can allocate and attach parameters once, then set the `.Connection` and the parameter values anew for each query. In practice, you will find this hardly matters -- grouping commands in a transaction (thereby reducing the transaction log writes) is going to be a lot more noticeable.

Comment: Ironically (or otherwise) you'll find using multiple connections can actually speed things up, precisely because you cannot execute more than one command at a time on one connection. If you're currently limited to only one connection that you have to share everywhere, executing commands in parallel on their own connections can speed things up. So it's not just easier to manage, it's potentially faster too.

Comment: Understood - I will give it a try

Comment: @JeroenMostert Just for feedback. "Scope" wasn't the issue - another thread was overwriting the data...

Comment: Then scope was arguably still the issue -- not the scope of the connection object, but the scope of your data. Sharing data is the great enemy of concurrency. :-)